# Trigger Facebook dialog on proper Luis intent

Tags: c#, botframework

I want to use Facebook authentication to my bot. So far, I am following [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/SimpleFacebookAuthBot).

I want to trigger the Facebook dialog when some Luis intent is in scope.

For example, I want to something similar to what I have in my `MessagesController`:

```
 await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new RootLuisDialog());
```

but in my Luis dialog:

```
public async Task help(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{
   await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => SimpleFacebookAuthDialog.dialog);
}
```

How to send proper activity to Facebook dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `context.Call` or `context.Forward` in order to call a child dialog.

```
context.Call(SimpleFacebookAuthDialog.dialog, this.ResumeAfterAuth);
```

You might need to check the [MultiDialogs sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-MultiDialogs) to grasp some of the concepts involved.